# For python or C++ program files I am looking for added meta information

Tags: metadata

I am looking for the possibility adding meta information to program files afterwards.E.g I have a browser with 2 columns one with file name and the second with meta information like keywords etc. and I must not open the program file in an editor for that. Does anyone have a idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello Claus and welcome to SO. Could you perhaps define your question a bit more clearly? Also, i would recomend you to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When I open e.g sublime editor I see on the left hand all my python or C++ program files with a filename xyz.py, abc.py etc. Only when I open one file in the editor  I see what the program does. Is there any editor where I can describe as meta text what the program does or/and added some keywords. I hope that is more clearly - Claus

Comment: Hi Claus, Do you have a screenshot of an example elsewhere on your computer where this meta information is displayed for other programs?

Comment: I am a little frustrated. I thought my question is simple and anyone who does a lot of programming could recommend me a  tool how to best document a program - Claus